# Width of input field only works with px

Tags: html, css

Im trying to set the width of my input field to 80% but whenever I change it to % it doesn't work.

My html:

```
<div class="todo">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="b2">
        Ends:<input class="finishDate" [(ngModel)]="toDo$.finishDate">
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My full css of my todo component.

```
   @media  screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .todo {
    display:flex;
  }
}


.b1 input[type=text]{
  text-decoration: underline#334A5A ;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:19px;
  font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
  color:#0C1824;
}
input {
  border:none;
  outline: none;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.delete {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Are there any styes on any of the divs?

Comment: It should work & it seems priority issue. What if `.todo .content .b2 input{ width:100%; }`

Comment: Please share the CSS on surrounding container elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make it dynamic so that you don't need to ever hard-code the `width`?

- Use `flexbox`
- Surround your conceptual label with a real `<label>` and point it to the `id` of the `input` (added). When you click a label, it focuses the cursor into the associated `input`
- Tell the input to take up the most possible space in the row, leaving the rest for the `label`

```css
input {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.b2 {
  display: flex;
}

.finishDate {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="todo">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="b2">
        <label for="finishDate">Ends:</label>
        <input id="finishDate" class="finishDate">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to your code for the input

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sxh3ecuy/1/)

Comment: Doesn't do anything.

Comment: can you check the demo ? because it is your code with percentage width and `box-sizing: border-box;` plus I changed the border for better understanding